# Hybrid WebForms/ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET MVC alongside Web Forms in the same web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288840/asp-net-mvc-alongside-web-forms-in-the-same-web-app)

I am kinda new to .NET applications, I have a web forms application that I am working on and I am about to start the development of new pages, I am trying to make the new pages with the ASP.NET MVC, but I am not beeing able to make the pages hit the controllers. First i added the library references added the routes on the global.asax but not sure what else is missing, can someone help me out?

thx.

Answer (score 6):

Reading between the lines I gather you are trying to **add** MVC pages to your existing ASP.NET Webforms Webapplication?

If that is the case then you probably need some MVC specific config. settings. Easiest way is to create a new MVC web app and then merge the config settings.

Furthermore if you are doing a hybrid project I'd recommend giving [Scott Hanselmann's post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx) on the topic a read.

Comment: I second this opinion on comparing Web.config ASP.NET MVC settings with the existing ones and considering a careful merge.

Answer (score 2):

There's a more step-by-step description of adding MVC to a WebForms Application at these links:

- [Integrating ASP.Net MVC Into An Existing ASP.Net Web Application](http://blogs.imeta.co.uk/MGodfrey/archive/2009/03/31/663.aspx)
- [Mixing ASP.NET Webforms and ASP.NET MVC](http://www.packtpub.com/article/mixing-asp.net-webforms-and-asp.net-mvc)

You might also want to add the ProjectTypeGuid to the project file with a text editor ({603c0e0b-db56-11dc-be95-000d561079b0} is used to designate to Visual Studio to use the MVC extensions.)

```
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{603c0e0b-db56-11dc-be95-000d561079b0};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

The links above also don't fully cover the system.webserver area of web.config that needs to be configured.

Answer (score 0):

Scott Hanselman released a "totally unsupported" Nuget package that adds MVC 3 features to an existing Web Forms project.  It also works on my PC (ha ha) and I've used it on several projects.

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/AddMvc3ToWebForms

He blogged about it here:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingANuGetPackageIn7EasyStepsPlusUsingNuGetToIntegrateASPNETMVC3IntoExistingWebFormsApplications.aspx

One newb tip: this package will configure your MVC routes in /App_Start/RegisterMvc3Routes.cs

Answer (score 0):

I've spent a lot of time over the past few months on this. Here are my observations.

The good/easy
 - Getting `Webforms` to call into `MVC` controllers
 - It was remarkably easy to stand up a new `MVC3` project and drop `Webforms` pages into it.
 - I was able to move my `<pages><controls></controls></pages>` section into the `/pages` directory in a new `web.config` there

The dirty/difficult

- [Regarding the `GUID`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/994159/57883)

  - Please note that the `GUID` has to be added at the front of the line for some reason... everytime I tried it failed. Until I stumbled on a post that insisted it be the before the others.
  - also I don't know what the difference is but I have a different GUID working... `{E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401}`
- getting the landing page to be `Webforms` caused ALL kinds of snags.
- getting jQuery intellisense to play nicely with `T4MVC`

this is what I did to address that

```
@if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
    { 
    <script src="../../Scripts/Mvc3/jquery-1.7-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script> @* intellisense! *@
     @Html.RelativeJavascript(Links.Scripts.Mvc3.jquery_1_7_js)
     @Html.RelativeJavascript(Links.Scripts.Mvc3.jquery_unobtrusive_ajax_js)
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.RelativeJavascript(Links.Scripts.Mvc3.jquery_1_7_min_js) 
        @Html.RelativeJavascript(Links.Scripts.Mvc3.jquery_unobtrusive_ajax_min_js)  
    }
```

Recommendations:

- Use [`T4MVC`](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC) in ALL cases even if you are pure webforms. The elimination of magic strings for static content (`.js`,`.css`, images, specifying templates) is outstanding.

  - and if you have any part of your [build process compiling views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8391459/57883) then you get compile-time safety on any of those links.