# ASP.NET MVC alongside Web Forms in the same web app?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Has anyone successfully deployed ASP.NET MVC alongside Web Forms in the same application in a production environment? Were there any conflicts or gotchas you faced while doing so?

Is it really as easy as shown [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/Contents/Item/Display/107) in practice? What about if you run a MVC using the Razor view engine alongside Web Forms?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mvc is build on top of asp.net as is webforms, so yes it's easy. 
Done it couple of times for conversion purposes

Maybe this url's could help you:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx

and

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx

Comment: Have you run a MVC using the Razor view engine alongside Web Forms?

Comment: Yes I have. Used these two while converting a webforms application to mvc 3. You have to do some manual stuff though compared to a newly created standard mvc3 application.

Answer (score 3):

One gotcha is don't put your `WebForms` inside the Views folder. I haven't get figured how to make `MVC` leave those paths alone. None of the ignore routing instructions seems to work in this case and the `WebForms` throw 404s.

Other than that `WebForms` works perfectly fine alongside `MVC` since `MVC2`.

Answer (score 2):

> Has anyone successfully deployed ASP.NET MVC alongside Web Forms in
>   the same application in a production environment?

I never mixed ASP.NET MVC and classic WebForms in the same application. I make them run in separate applications and communicate between them with standard HTTP techniques (query string parameters, form posts, cookies, ...).

> Is it really as easy as shown here in practice?

Yes, it is as easy as that.

Comment: How is this easier than running them both in the same app? It seems like managing communication between separate apps using HTTP is more work than making a call to a class in the same assembly.

Comment: @T. Webster, I didn't say that it is easier. It is cleaner. Polluting a new ASP.NET MVC application inside some existing WebForms application is always a bad idea. You will be tempted to do things that you should never do in an ASP.NET MVC application. You will definitely end up with ugly code that will need rewriting later. Personally I prefer to do tings in a clean fashion when migrating an application, even if it might be a little harder indeed, but to know that at the end I will be happy with the result.

Answer (score 2):

Check out scott hanselmans AddMvc3ToWebForms nuget package. I am using it and its working pretty great. I am using it to gradually convert my web forms app to mvc

Comment: Nice, but before I can mark this as an answer I'll have to try it for myself.

Answer (score 2):

I've spent a lot of time over the past few months on this. Here are my observations.

The good/easy
 - Getting `Webforms` to call into `MVC` controllers
 - It was remarkably easy to stand up a new `MVC3` project and drop `Webforms` pages into it.
 - I was able to move my `<pages><controls></controls></pages>` section into the `/pages` directory in a new `web.config` there

The dirty/difficult

- [Regarding the `GUID`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/994159/57883)

  - Please note that the `GUID` has to be added at the front of the line for some reason... everytime I tried it failed. Until I stumbled on a post that insisted it be the before the others.
  - also I don't know what the difference is but I have a different GUID working... `{E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401}`
- getting the landing page to be `Webforms` caused ALL kinds of snags.
- getting jQuery intellisense to play nicely with `T4MVC`

this is what I did to address that

```
@if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
    { 
    <script src="../../Scripts/Mvc3/jquery-1.7-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script> @* intellisense! *@
     @Html.RelativeJavascript(Links.Scripts.Mvc3.jquery_1_7_js)
     @Html.RelativeJavascript(Links.Scripts.Mvc3.jquery_unobtrusive_ajax_js)
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.RelativeJavascript(Links.Scripts.Mvc3.jquery_1_7_min_js) 
        @Html.RelativeJavascript(Links.Scripts.Mvc3.jquery_unobtrusive_ajax_min_js)  
    }
```

Recommendations:

- Use [`T4MVC`](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC) in ALL cases even if you are pure webforms. The elimination of magic strings for static content (`.js`,`.css`, images, specifying templates) is outstanding.

  - and if you have any part of your [build process compiling views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8391459/57883) then you get compile-time safety on any of those links.